# Fullwidth div rotation doesn't take maximum width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a full width rotated header but the problem is that when I rotate it in the right corner of the header it has a space. I've made a jsfiddle to understand my problem better. I'm trying hours and hours many methods but nothing worked. Thank you

```
#header {
background: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
height: 150px;
transform: rotate(356deg) ;
-webkit-transform: rotate(356deg) ;
-moz-transform: rotate(356deg) ;
-o-transform: rotate(356deg) ;
-ms-transform: rotate(356deg) ;
-webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SAVw6/

Comment: So you basically just want the header to continue on to the left and right?

Comment: Exactly! I didn't explain it right. My head is gonna explode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is what you want:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SAVw6/5/

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container"><div id="header"></div><div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#header {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
    height: 150px;
    transform: rotate(356deg) ;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(356deg) ;
    -moz-transform: rotate(356deg) ;
    -o-transform: rotate(356deg) ;
    -ms-transform: rotate(356deg) ;
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
    width: 130%;
    margin-left: -20%;
}
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

- The container prevents any excess horizontal scrolling
- The width is extended above `100%` in order for it to continue on to the right and left.
- The margin-left is set to negative in order for it to continue to the left instead of only to the right.
- Your `-webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;` CSS code is specifically targeting Chrome and no other browsers.  For cross-browser support, you can use:

  ```css
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  ```

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I'm stupid.. I forgot to add moz prefix on origin! Everything ok now! Thanks!